# Unexpected `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor` when creating a new vanilla Web Component

Tags: javascript, custom-component

I'm testing the limits of the [JavaScript Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) API and I encountered an interesting issue.

I have the following wrapper around an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object:

```
export class Wrapper {
  public el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(elementName: string) {
    this.el = document.createElement(elementName);
    customElements.get(elementName) ||
      customElements.define(elementName, HTMLElement);
  }
}
```

I use this implementation because HTMLElement has a series of limitations I want to bypass, e.g. the constructor must be empty.

Then, I instanciate the wrapper and append the actual element to the DOM:

```
let wrapper = new Wrapper("magic-component")
document.body.appendChild(wrapper.el);
```

To my surprise, this throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

It appears [this error happens when a custom element is created via `new` before being defined via `customElements.define()`.](https://jonas.arnklint.com/illegal-constructor-web-component-custom-element) However, this is not the case here: this.el is regularly created via `document.createElement()` and then defined via `customElements.define()`. Only the wrapper is created via `new`.

```js
class Wrapper {
  constructor(elementName) {
    this.el = document.createElement(elementName);
    customElements.get(elementName) ||
      customElements.define(elementName, HTMLElement);
  }
}

let wrapper = new Wrapper("magic-component")
document.body.appendChild(wrapper.el);
```

Comment: Its harder to explain with these lines. Can you add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Sure, no problem. I added a snippet to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what magic you are after.

With `customElements.define` you need to properly **extend** HTMLElement

```js
class Wrapper {
  constructor(elementName) {
    customElements.get(elementName) ||
      customElements.define(elementName, class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          this.innerHTML = elementName
        }
      });
    return document.createElement(elementName);
  }
}

let wrapper = new Wrapper("magic-component")
document.body.append(wrapper);
```

But why the, kinda oldskool, `new Wrapper`?

```js
function newElement(elementName) {
  customElements.get(elementName) ||
    customElements.define(elementName, class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = elementName
      }
    });
  return document.createElement(elementName);
}

document.body.append(newElement("magic-component"));
```

Note: once `magic-component` exists the *CustomElementsRegistry*; you *can* also do:

```js
customElements.define(
  "another-element", 
  class extends customElements.get("magic-component") {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = this.nodeName; // ANOTHER-ELEMENT
    }
});
```

#### Mixins

If you are after *mixins*, see: https://component.kitchen/elix/mixins